# Passing variable to same controller getting error "Too few arguments to function"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, axios

> In my controller I got error Too few argument to function

```php
    public function getpayrollID($id)
    {
        $fetch2 = DB::table('payroll_details')->where('payroll_daily_id',$id)  
       ->get();
                foreach($fetch as $payrollID){
                    $payroll_id = $payrollID->payroll_daily_id;
                }
    
       }
        public function payroll($id,$payroll_id)
        {
            $fetch = DB::table('payroll_attendance')->where('wrk_id',$id)
            ->where('payroll_daily_id',$payroll_id)
    
            ->select(DB::raw('count(wrk_id) as totattn')) 
           ->get();
    
            return $fetch;
          
        
        }
```

> may route in web.php

```php
Route::get('api/payroll_date/{id}','API\payrollController@payroll');
Route::get('api/payroll_id/{id}','API\payrollController@getpayrollID')
```

> Im using axios get

axios.get('/api/getpayroll_id/'+ this.$route.params.id).then(({data})=>{
(this.payroll_id = data);

```
    axios.get('/api/payroll_date/'+ this.wrk_id).then(({data})=>{
      (this.payrolldate = data);
```

Comment: your route `payroll` and function `getpayrollID` don't match please add correct one or fixed that

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the route. pls check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to accrpt `($id,$payroll_id)`  parameter then u need to accept from route as well

```php
Route::get('api/payroll_id/{id}/{payroll_id}','API\payrollController@getpayrollID')
```

or if u not sure if second parameter you can mark it optional by `?` this symbol like

```php
Route::get('api/payroll_id/{id}/{payroll_id?}','API\payrollController@getpayrollID')
```

Comment: @azakura check now

Comment: @azakura in `getpayrollID` function don't have any return statement

Comment: I want return data in payroll

Comment: even I put return in `getpayrollID` function it returns nothing in `payroll` function

Comment: @azakura did't get what u want to achive

Comment: in `getpayrollID` I just want to get the variable having payroll_id and pass it on `payroll` because Im using  two where clause

Comment: `payroll_id `  will be array .? u r using foreach

Comment: No its not an array I just want to extract it so i can get the Id on it

Comment: the problem is why isnt displaying if I try to remove {$payroll_id} in route it works.. It means passing paroll_id in route is not working

Answer (score 0):

You are geting two variable in your method and you pass one variable in route try this

```
Route::get('api/payroll_date/{id}/{payroll_id}','API\payrollController@payroll');
```

I hope this is your answer.

Comment: use above route for your payroll method

Answer (score 0):

change the routes as :

```php
Route::get('api/payroll_date/{id}/{payroll_id}','API\payrollController@payroll');
Route::get('api/payroll_id/{id}','API\payrollController@getpayrollID')
```

Besides when you call payroll you should send two argument :

```php
axios.get('/api/payroll_date/'+ this.wrk_id+'/'+payroll_id).then(({data})=>{
      (this.payrolldate = data);
```